# Tag synonyms not working as intended

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

I'm pretty sure the Tag Syonyms is not working as intended.

Take the following example, for the tag counter-strike-go.

[tag synonym http://puu.sh/a5ofM/7be5e35b7b.png](http://puu.sh/a5ofM/7be5e35b7b.png)

Looks fine right? "global offensive" is listed as a synonym. Not so, when finding a tag:

[image: tag synonym]

So even though the fact is that `cs-global-offensive` is a synonym of the `counter-strike-go tag`, the `global` in `cs-global-offensive` isn't being recognized at all; it seems that the tag system doesn't actually look up synonyms; only their main counterparts.

Or how RavenDreamer put it:

> I believe his point is that `global-agenda` and `pokemon-global`
>   link show up, but `cs-global-offensive` does not (despite the latter
>   being an extant tag synonym)

[Tag synonyms not working as intended](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9771/tag-synonyms-not-working-as-intended?noredirect=1#comment27178_9771)

Comment: I'm not sure how that's *not* working as intended.  How is *any* system supposed to know what is and isn't a valid synonym without an exact match?

Comment: Just like how when you enter a question title, it doesn't search for related questions by an exact string, but by extracting bits of the question that are similar to other questions.  Tags should do the same.

Comment: Tags have a ton less context to go off of then what is required for titles and the body of a question.  You have, *at most* 25 characters.  I'm still not seeing a viable method beyond exact matches.  Or how this current functionality isn't intended.  Perhaps it might be better to just propose one or two more synonyms for CS:GO, rather than attempting to change the entire tagging system.

Comment: @Frank I believe his point is that `**global** agenda` and `pokemon **global** link `show up, but `cs **global** offensive` does not (despite the latter being an extant tag synonym).

Comment: That's a good thing to describe, as nowhere in this does it describe that at all.

Comment: The problem seems to be common to all SE sites (tested on RPG and SciFi). Partial matches of synonyms don't make the Master tag show up. This problem should be addressed on the Main Meta, since it would be core functionality, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging around on different sites and Metas, and found that this problem is extremely weird, and the behavior completely undefined.

First of all, here's a list of similar topics:

- [Searching for synonyms on the Tags page seems very inconsistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174044/searching-for-synonyms-on-the-tags-page-seems-very-inconsistent) (META SE)
- [Existing tag not shown when searching in the list of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224818/existing-tag-not-shown-when-searching-in-the-list-of-tags) (META SE)
- https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/autocomplete-tag-synonyms (Judaism META)
- https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/tag-search-should-match-middle-of-synonyms (Judaism META)

---

I used the tag list and the tag box on a new question on

- Arqade using "cs-global-offensive" = "counter-strike-go"
- META SE using "on-topic-definition" = "scope"
- RPG SE using "scenario-authoring" = "adventure-writing"

To see what shows up and what does not. I will mention only synonyms for the Master tag, even if they differ from the one I tried.

#### Arqade

- "cs-": List shows "cs-global-offensive" and "csgo", Question shows nothing
- "cs-g": List shows "csgo", Question shows nothing
- "global": List shows "global-offensive", Question shows nothing
- "cs-global-offensive": List shows "cs-global-offensive", Questions shows Master

#### RPG

- "scenario-": List shows "scenario-authoring", Question shows nothing
- "scenario-a": List shows nothing, Question shows nothing
- "authoring": List shows nothing, Question shows nothing
- "scenario-authoring": List shows "scenario-authoring", Questions shows Master

#### META

- "on-": List shows many different ones, Question shows 6 different ones
- "on-t": List shows nothing, Question shows Master
- "topic": List shows nothing, Question shows Master
- "on-topic-discussion": List shows nothing, Question shows Master

Analyzing this, Arqade and RPG behave the same, partials matching the beginning of the synonym show the synonym in the tag list, the Question tag box needs the fully correct synonym to display anything at all. Other sides (Judaism and Math) seem to share this behavior as far as I can tell from the topics I linked.

META seems to not show synonyms in their tag-list at all, and any partial match seems to show the master, though only 6 matches are shown at any time.

---

IMO, any partial match of a synonym should show the master in both the tag list and the question tag box. There's no need to show something to a user that is discouraged to use/will be automatically replaced anyway.

None of the sites I looked at have that behavior, but partial synonym-matching works for the question tag box on META SE, so we know it can be done.

Comment: I have turned this into a question on META: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236625/partial-tag-synonym-matching-behavior-across-different-sites-and-functions